# call on somebody

Tags: word-usage

I came across the following sentences in a textbook:

> Ashley backs me up when I need her. She'll be there for me if I call on her.

I looked it up on [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/call-on):

> **call on or call upon  (call on someone/something to do something)**
>
> to officially ask a person or organization to do something
>
> *The human rights group has called on the US to end the death penalty.*
>
> **(call on someone)**
>
> to visit someone, usually for a short time
>
> *We could call on my parents if we have time.*

I'm a bit confused. Is the phrasal verb 'call on' used correctly in the above-mentioned sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a correct usage of the first definition you quoted. The request doesn’t need to be as “official” as they indicate, though, just explicit.